# Chrome tab syncing across devices not working

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, sync

I've found this guide to sync Chrome tabs across devices and I enabled sync on both devices. Nothings happening though when I enabled tab sync on my PC and Notebook. How do I open the tabs from one device on the other? Both devices run Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

http://www.howtogeek.com/96664/how-to-sync-open-tabs-across-computers-using-google-chrome/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article that you are referring to was published in 2011.

When opening Chrome, or chromium, it is stated at the top of the page that:

***WARNING These experimental features may change, break, or disappear at any time...***

It does appear to be the case that the option within "http:// flags" has indeed disappeared.

That particular option of syncing open tabs is not available in either chromium(Version 25.0.1364.160) or Chrome stable(Version 26.0.1410.43) on Ubuntu 12.04.02.

Take a look a more recent guide, from Google, regarding the [Sync tabs across devices](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=2591582) functionality.

However, there is an option to look at the open tabs on some other devices(see note below).

1. You need to be signed-in a Google account to use this functionality.
2. Open wrench in upper right hand corner of your browser
3. Select "Advanced sync settings"

   [image]
4. Open a new tab
5. Look in the lower right hand corner of the browser and click on the area that say "Other devices" as indicated below:

   [image]

**Note: I can't speak to how this functionality works across all devices. My tablet syncs partially but my android phone does not appear to sync completely (it only shows most recent tab-singular. YMMV).**

It sounds like you are looking for functionality that will allow you to open *all* tabs open on a remote computer. In that case, I would recommend using the [Xmarks plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xmarks-bookmark-sync/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla?hl=en)

See also: http://www.xmarks.com/ and http://blog.xmarks.com/